# Why can I not deselect "encrypt my home folder"?

Tags: installation, 13.04, ecryptfs

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04, but didn't want to encrypt my home folder. The installer doesn't let me uncheck the option.

[image]

Why?

Comment: Are you getting this while installing or after the installation is finished?

Comment: @Mitch: while installing (see screenshot below)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you upgrading a previous install (or using an existing Home partion)?

If so this is most probably because you previously installed Ubuntu with an encrypted home folder. The installer automatially detects this. You cannot unset "Encrypt my home folder" as you would not be able to access your files otherwise.

It is **very important** that you select the same login password as before. If needed you can change it after the instalation.

Comment: Nice. That was the mistake. I backed up my data before manually out of the ecrypt storem, but the .ecryptfs and .Private symlinks were still in the homefolder (felix.old). I guess the setup searches for these folders and then decides that the home folder is encrypted. Finally I removed .ecryptfs and .Private from my home directory and now it works. Thank you.

Comment: Clarification request: What is "login password" ? Is that "password" or "both login and password"?

Comment: its the password your user uses to log in (just "password")