# Xubuntu 18.04 Reinstall Deleted Files in /home

Tags: xubuntu

I recently reinstalled Xubuntu 18.04. My partition scheme consists of a partition for /, /home and swap. I checked format for / but not /home. However, after the installation, most of the contents of /home were gone (I know, I should have made a backup before installing). Folders like Downloads, Videos, Pictures and so on are completely empty, but /home still has 1.2TB of data in .ecryptfs and .steam.

Can the original data from Downloads and other folders be found somewhere else on the partition? If not, what is the best method of recovery?

Comment: Since your original home directory was encrypted, did you take care to choose the same username and password for the reinstalled system? For background, see [Why can I not deselect “encrypt my home folder”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291986/why-can-i-not-deselect-encrypt-my-home-folder)